# Getting maximum call stack Error in React/Vite app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am encountering a maximum call stack error when using a React component with a function (highlightText) that manipulates the text and causes issues during hot reload with Vite. The error specifically occurs when I **save the file**, and Vite attempts to perform a hot reload. If I use the app normally I don't see any errors but as soon as I save the file in vs code I see this error.

```
const DeckAndCardResult: FC<PropType> = ({
  foundDecks,
  foundCards,
  setFoundDecks,
  setEditData,
  editData,
  searchQuery,
}) => {


const highlightText = useCallback(
    (text: string, searchQuery: string) => {
      // here we will escape special characters because they have some meaning in regular expression.
      // for eg. if you put "/" in search string ("react/") this will throw an error so we will escape "/" and then search it.
      const escapedSearchQuery = searchQuery.replace(
        /[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,
        "\\$&"
      );

      // Create a regular expression to match the search query.
      const regex = new RegExp(`(${escapedSearchQuery})`, "gi");

      // Split the text using the regular expression and keep track of the first match.
      let isFirstMatch = false;
      const foundString = text.split(regex).map((part, index) => {
        // Check if the current part matches the search query.
        if (regex.test(part) && !isFirstMatch) {
          isFirstMatch = true;
          // Highlight the first occurrence.
          return (
            <span
              key={index}
              className={`${theme === "dark" ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-yellow-300"}`}
            >
              {part}
            </span>
          );
        } else {
          return part;
        }
      });

      return <>{foundString}</>;
    },
    [theme]
  );

 return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center items-center  mx-2 lg:mx-52 mb-48 gap-4 animate-quickOpacity">
        {foundCards?.map((card, index) => (
          <Link
            onClick={handleShowUserInfomation}
            key={card.cardId}
            to={`/search/result/${card.deck_id}/${card.cardIndex}`}
            state={{ from: location.pathname, card }}
          >
            <div className="border relative border-gray-400 flex flex-col text-gray-800 rounded-md px-2 py-2 h-[8.8rem] lg:h-40 text-justify lg:w-[50vw] w-[95vw] transition-[background-color,border-color] duration-300  dark:hover:bg-slate-900 dark:hover:border-sky-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:border-teal-500 group">
              <p className="font-bold text-md lg:text-lg text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-50 mb-1 p-1 line-clamp-1 break-words break-all -ml-1 ">
                {searchQuery.length > 0 &&
                  highlightText(card.title, searchQuery)}
              </p>
              <p className="text-sm lg:text-base  text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100 px-1 line-clamp-3 break-words break-all -ml-1">
                {searchQuery.length > 0 &&
                  highlightText(card.note, searchQuery)}
              </p>
              <p className="absolute text-gray-50 bg-teal-800 group-hover:bg-teal-700   dark:bg-sky-800  dark:group-hover:bg-sky-700 transition duration-300 right-0 bottom-0 px-2 rounded-br-[0.340rem] rounded-tl-md line-clamp-1 break-all text-center  max-w-[10rem]">
                {card.deckTitle}
              </p>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

As you can see I am calling highlightText function in JSX like this.

```
 <p className="text-sm lg:text-base  text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100 px-1 line-clamp-3 break-words break-all -ml-1">
    {searchQuery.length > 0 && highlightText(card.note, searchQuery)}
 </p>
```

**I know this is the problem because when I remove this function call from JSX I stop getting the error.**

```
const DeckAndCardResult: FC<PropType> = ({
  foundDecks,
  foundCards,
  setFoundDecks,
  setEditData,
  editData,
  searchQuery,
}) => {


const highlightText = useCallback(
    (text: string, searchQuery: string) => {
      // here we will escape special characters because they have some meaning in regular expression.
      // for eg. if you put "/" in search string ("react/") this will throw an error so we will escape "/" and then search it.
      const escapedSearchQuery = searchQuery.replace(
        /[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,
        "\\$&"
      );

      // Create a regular expression to match the search query.
      const regex = new RegExp(`(${escapedSearchQuery})`, "gi");

      // Split the text using the regular expression and keep track of the first match.
      let isFirstMatch = false;
      const foundString = text.split(regex).map((part, index) => {
        // Check if the current part matches the search query.
        if (regex.test(part) && !isFirstMatch) {
          isFirstMatch = true;
          // Highlight the first occurrence.
          return (
            <span
              key={index}
              className={`${theme === "dark" ? "bg-red-500" : "bg-yellow-300"}`}
            >
              {part}
            </span>
          );
        } else {
          return part;
        }
      });

      return <>{foundString}</>;
    },
    [theme]
  );

 return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center items-center  mx-2 lg:mx-52 mb-48 gap-4 animate-quickOpacity">
        {foundCards?.map((card, index) => (
          <Link
            onClick={handleShowUserInfomation}
            key={card.cardId}
            to={`/search/result/${card.deck_id}/${card.cardIndex}`}
            state={{ from: location.pathname, card }}
          >
            <div className="border relative border-gray-400 flex flex-col text-gray-800 rounded-md px-2 py-2 h-[8.8rem] lg:h-40 text-justify lg:w-[50vw] w-[95vw] transition-[background-color,border-color] duration-300  dark:hover:bg-slate-900 dark:hover:border-sky-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:border-teal-500 group">
              <p className="font-bold text-md lg:text-lg text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-50 mb-1 p-1 line-clamp-1 break-words break-all -ml-1 ">
                {searchQuery.length > 0 &&
             card.title}
              </p>
              <p className="text-sm lg:text-base  text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100 px-1 line-clamp-3 break-words break-all -ml-1">
                {searchQuery.length > 0 &&
             card.note}
              </p>
              <p className="absolute text-gray-50 bg-teal-800 group-hover:bg-teal-700   dark:bg-sky-800  dark:group-hover:bg-sky-700 transition duration-300 right-0 bottom-0 px-2 rounded-br-[0.340rem] rounded-tl-md line-clamp-1 break-all text-center  max-w-[10rem]">
                {card.deckTitle}
              </p>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

In above code I am not using hightlightText function I am showing text directly. when I do this I don't get any errors when I save the file.
I don't understand what is the problem. the problem occures only when I save the file.

[image]